# Bootstrap3 DateTimePicker: minDate option set the input value field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a problem where setting the `minDate` option set the input value field. Why??

(When I write this post, input date is after `minDate`)

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h6>datetimepicker</h6>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" value="21/12/2016"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    //minDate: moment(), If I uncomment it the input value field changes to current date
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y4x6j5m/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the [`useCurrent`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) option and set it to `false`.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'fr',
  minDate: moment(),
  useCurrent: false,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h6>datetimepicker</h6>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker" value="21/12/2016"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and in my case, it seems that the correct parameters are   ``minDate: moment(), useCurrent: false,defaultDate: moment()``. That way if value is empty, I use the ``defaultDate`` and if value is set, I use that one.